# Interactive Brokers returns multiple "presubmitted" order statuses for a single order

Tags: c++, posix, interactive-brokers

Has anyone experienced multiple order statuses per sent order?
Is there a way to fix this or what is the best way to deal with it?

```
./PosixSocketClientTest 10.1.55.2
Start of POSIX Socket Client Test 0
Attempt 1 of 50
Connecting to 10.1.55.2:7496 clientId:0
Connected to 10.1.55.2:7496 clientId:0
Placing Order 42: BUY 1000 IBM at 0.010000
Order: id=42, status=PreSubmitted
Requesting Current Time
The current date/time is: Sat May 7 12:20:04 2016
Order: id=42, status=PreSubmitted
Order: id=42, status=Cancelled
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/c/orderstatus.htm

> Note:  It is possible that orderStatus() may return duplicate
>   messages. It is essential that you filter the message accordingly.

There's 2 fields, filled and remaining that I watch to know how the order is doing.  When remaining is 0, it's all done.  That way you also know if it's a partial fill.